# Android colors with minus

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a red color in `R.colors` which has value `#FF0000`.

When I use

`ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red)`

it returns `-65536`

Is there any solution?

Comment: What is the problem? `#FF0000` in hex is -65536 in decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what is **supposed** to be returned.

the function `ContextCompat.getColor()` return an int representation of the color.

No worries tho, use this returned value in any color function that gets an int. for example `TextView1.setTextColor(your_value)`.

Answer (score 1):

[**`ContextCompat.getColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int))

> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID.

A single color value in the form **`0xAARRGGBB`**. Decimal Format.

**FYI**

```
    val color = Color.parseColor("#FF0000")
    System.out.println("Decimal"+color) //-65536
```